# Laravel: How to use a translation API

Tags: laravel, api

I am trying to use a translation API with Laravel.
There's a list of products in my DB and what I want to do is translate those products using the API. I am given a sample code to use the API but I have two questions.
Here's the sample code.

```
<?php
require 'vendor\autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

session_start();

define('URL', '');
define('KEY', '');
define('SECRET', '');
define('NAME', '');

$api_name = '';
$api_param = '';

$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider(
    [
        'clientId'                => KEY,                            // API Key
        'clientSecret'            => SECRET,                         // API secret
        'redirectUri'             => '',                             
        'urlAuthorize'            => '',                             
        'urlAccessToken'          => URL . '/oauth2/token.php',      // URI for access token
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    ],
);

try {

    // Try to get an access token using the authorization code grant.
    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('client_credentials');

    // The provider provides a way to get an authenticated API request for
    // the service, using the access token; it returns an object conforming
    // to Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface.
    
    $params = array(
        'access_token' => $accessToken->getToken(),                   // access token
        'key' => KEY,                                                 // API Key
        'api_name' => $api_name,
        'api_param' => $api_param,
        'name' => NAME,                                               // log in ID
        'type' => 'xml',                                              // response type
        'xxx' => 'xxx',    
    );

    $request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
        'POST',
        URL . '/api/?' . http_build_query($params),                    // URL + URL parameter
        $accessToken,
    );

    $response = $provider->getResponse($request);
    $data = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    print_r($data);

} catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {

    // Failed to get the access token or user details.
    exit($e->getMessage());

}
```

First thing I want to ask is if I'm suppose to wright this code in the Controller or the Model.

Second thing that I'm stuck with is how to alter the sample code to translate variables in the view file. This is what the view file looks like.

```
                        @foreach($user->products as $pro)
                        @if($pro->category_id == 1)
                            <div class="menu"><div class="menu-description">
                                <div class="title-price">
                                    <h2>{{ $pro->name }}</h2>
                                    <h2>￥{{ $pro->price }}</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    {{ $pro->description }}
                                </div>                                  
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
```

I want to translate is {{ $pro->name }} part. I think for the current sample code, if I enter something like 'text' => 'apple' in $params, That will be translated but I'm not sure how to alter this code to translate variables in the view file.

Any smallest help would be appreciated as I'm new to Laravel and completely lost here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for something like this I'd setup a service that is in:

`namespace App\Services;`

Then I'd have some function in this service do the API call and return the formatted response, something like

```
class Translator
{
    public function translate($word){
        \\ in here you want to do your API calling for the relevant word / words.
    }
}
```